# Unable to see last item in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I am drawing scroll view with static **Button**.But Button is overlapping with static button.
So i am unable to access all items in the activity.
But i want to draw OK button always.but i am unable to look the some part of the screen.

Code is like below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:background="#2E9AFE" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Present Details"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Present Location"
         />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPreLoc1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPreLoc1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Coming By"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mmsComing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Vehicle details"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDriver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Expected time to reach by:"
         />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="75" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mmsOk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: post the whole layout

Comment: @blackbelt : full code added

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#2E9AFE" >



    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Present Details"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvtv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Present Location"
                />

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPreLoc1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etPreLoc1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Coming By"
                />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mmsComing"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Vehicle details"
                />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDriver"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Expected time to reach by:"
                />

        <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="75" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/mmsOk"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="25"
             android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```